# If I select Improved Natural Attack (Claws), does that apply to Rake attacks too?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, animal-companions, natural-weapon

Claws and Rakes are listed as separate attacks, but Rake's are extra attacks by the creature's claws.

If I selected Improved Natural Attack for my Lion Animal Companion, do my Rake attacks also benefit from larger damage dice provided by Improved Natural Attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes, Rake attacks benefit from Improved Natural Attack (Claws).

From the [AONPRD](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Rake) on Rake (**emphasis mine**):

> A creature with this special attack gains extra natural attacks under certain conditions, typically when it grapples its foe. In addition to the options available to all grapplers, a monster with the rake ability gains two free **claw** attacks that it can use only against a grappled foe. The bonus and damage caused by these attacks are included in the creature’s description.

Rake attacks *are* claw attacks. They differ from normal claw attacks in that they can only be made under specific circumstances and that they can *potentially* have a different *base* damage die (i.e. a creature could have a d8 claw attack and a d6 rake attack; Improved Natural Attack for claws would increase these to a d10 and a d8 because they are both claw attacks).